# Traductor en DeepL

Tags: python, deepl

Tengo este codigo en Python el cual deberia traducir una lista en excel de ingles a español; un tiempo me funciono muy bien pero al parecer esta linea `textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style`  cambio en la pagina de DeepL he buscado la forma de resolverlo sin buenos resultados, alguna idea?

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda

```
from pathlib import Path
import os.path as path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

in_file = str(Path(__file__).parent / Path("Update DB Activities.xlsm"))
wb = xw.Book(in_file)
wb.activate()
sht = wb.sheets['Codes update'].activate()
sht = wb.sheets['Codes update']

urow1 = sht.range('B1').end('down').last_cell.row
urow2 = sht.range('D1').end('down').last_cell.row
for i in range(int(urow2+1), int(urow1+1)):
    txt = sht.range(f'C{i}').value

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/' + txt)

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'textarea.lmt__textarea.lmt__target_textarea.lmt__textarea_base_style')))
        time.sleep(2)
        text_target = element.get_attribute('value')
        sht.range(f'D{i}').value = text_target
    except:
        sht.range(f'D{i}').value = "Error al traducir"

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: ¿Inspeccionaste la página para ver si coincide el elemento con la clase que mencionás? ¿Estás seguro/a que es un `textarea`?

Comment: @padaleiana Gracias por contestar el post, esto es lo que muestra la inspeccion del cuadro de traduccion ```d-textarea data-gramm_editor="false" dl-test="translator-target-input" autocomplete="off" lang="es-ES" aria-labelledby="translation-results-heading" class="lmt__textarea lmt__target_textarea lmt__textarea_base_style focus-visible-disabled-container"``` muestra resultado contenido en una clase ```textarea```

Comment: `d-textarea` <> `textarea`...

Comment: Además, la versión gratuita tiene limites de uso, ¿has probado navegar a la url y ver como funciona?

Comment: Si la utilizo bastante en mi trabajo, hay veces debo traducir listas muy extensas y por ello he buscado la forma de optimizar el proceso. Se que DeepL tiene limites en su servicio en cuentas gratuitas.

Comment: @padaleiana como me indicaste ```d-textarea``` esta era la solucion, mil gracias